# TypeScript - How to access constants based on environment? Like Cypress.env() outside of Cypress

Tags: node.js, typescript, environment-variables, automated-tests

Let's say I have this API test and the URL and Credentials differ between production and development environments:

```
 before("Get auth token", async () => {
    await spec().post(`${baseUrl}/auth`)
      .withBody(
        {
          email: "testing+standard@test.com",
          password: "test"
        }
      )
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expect((ctx) => {
        expect(ctx.res.body.token).to.be.a("string")
        state.token = ctx.res.body.token
      })
    }
  );
```

Now with Cypress tests you can have a json config file like this, one for each environment:

```
{
    "env": {
        "baseUrl": "example",
        "standardUserEmail": "testing+standard@test.com",
        "standardUserPassword": "test"
    }
}
```

Then access it like so:

```
cy.request({
      method: "POST",
      url: `${Cypress.env("baseUrl")}/auth`,
    })
```

How does one achieve something like this without using Cypress? A .env file doesn't solve this problem exactly and I also don't need one as I want the values stored in the repo.

**Answer (TypeScript version)**:

```
interface Environment {
    baseUrl: string;
    standardUserEmail: string;
    standardUserPassword: string
} 

type Environments = {
    development: Environment
    production: Environment
}

// Define environments with the relevant data as a map
const environments: Environments = {
    development:  {
        baseUrl: 'https://example.com',
        standardUserEmail: 'testing+standard@example.com',
        standardUserPassword: 'example',
    },
    production: {
        baseUrl: '',
        standardUserEmail: '',
        standardUserPassword: '',
    },
}

// Get the environment name from the command line
// or default to development
const getEnvironmentData = (): Environment => {
    const environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || 'development';
    console.log(`Using environment: ${environment}`);
    // Get the environment data from the map
    return environments[environment as keyof Environments]
};

// Export the environment data
export = getEnvironmentData()
```

Then use like this:

```
import 'mocha';
import { spec, request } from "pactum";
import { expect } from "chai"
import config from "../../config"

describe('Example Test API', function () {
  const state = {
    token: "",
  };

  before("Get auth token", async () => {
     request.setBaseUrl(config.baseUrl)
     await spec().post('/auth')
      .withBody(
        {
          email: config.standardUserEmail,
          password: config.standardUserPassword
        }
      )
      .expectStatus(200)
      .expect((ctx) => {
        expect(ctx.res.body.token).to.be.a("string")
        state.token = ctx.res.body.token
      })
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first example, looks like you are using PactumJS. If it's that you want to support multiple environments and be able to easily which between them, you can use a combination of environmental variables and a map of your environments, similar to how it was defined in Cypress.

```
// define your environments with the relevant data as a map
const environments = {
    development: {
        baseUrl: 'http://httpbin.org',
        standardUserEmail: 'dev+test@email.com',
        standardUserPassword: 'dev-test-password',
    },
    staging: {
        baseUrl: 'https://staging.example.com',
        standardUserEmail: 'stg+test@email.com',
        standardUserPassword: 'stg-test-password',
    },
    production: {
        baseUrl: 'https://example.com',
        standardUserEmail: 'prod+test@email.com',
        standardUserPassword: 'prod-test-password',
    },
}

// get the environment name from the command line
// or default to development
const getEnvironmentData = () => {
    const environment = process.env.ENVIRONMENT || 'development';
    console.log('Using environment: ', environment);
    // get the environment data from the map
    const environmentData = environments[environment];
    return environmentData;
};

// export the environment data
module.exports = {
    environmentData: getEnvironmentData(),
};
```

Once you have defined your map with all of the relevant data, you can reference them in your tests easily.

```
const { spec, request } = require('pactum');
const { environmentData } = require('../config');

before(() => {
    request.setBaseUrl(environmentData.baseUrl);
    console.log(environmentData.standardUserEmail);
    console.log(environmentData.standardUserPassword);
});

it('should get a response with status code 200', async () => {
    await spec()
        .get('/status/200')
        .expectStatus(200);
});
```

And finally, you can then easily switch between your environment data by using an environmental variable.

You will be accessing the variable by using `process.env.ENVIRONMENT`, which will be mapped back to the variable that you specify before your test command. See the image below:

[image]

For a working example: Please see the example project I created on GitHub: https://github.com/dimitriharding/pactumjs-with-dynamic-environtments

Comment: Amazing, thank you! This looks like it should do what I'm looking for, will modify for TypeScript and report back with result.

Comment: Tweaked for TypeScript and works great, thanks for the help! I can share code if interested.

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked out! Yes, I didn't write the example in TypeScript but I figured you would have been able to tweak it to work since it's just the concept I wanted to demonstrate.  Still, it would be good if you could share, in case others are looking for that version as well.

Comment: Updated question with TypeScript solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirements can be achieved using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv).
A sample use case can be found in [HackaTalk project](https://website.hackatalk.dev/docs/server/installation)

Comment: I don't believe so.